# possibility of creating an editor with custom markup

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

is it possible to create a new editor that includes custom markup? I went through the docs and couldn't find any extension to get it done.
My requirement is to develop an interactive graphical editor (with SVG) to manipulate text content in a file. I want to use third party css/js libs to implement the markup of the editor and at the same time using VS Code APIs fetch/update content of the current file, fire/listen to VS Code events, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions have very limited ability to manipulate the editor's UI.  It seems to me that you have two choices:

- If you need this capability to be unified with the editor, you will almost certainly need to fork VSCode.
- If you don't mind your added functionality being external to VSCode, you could create an extension with a language server that implements your UI.  The language server would run in a separate process, but would still be able to interact with VSCode through the extension.

Comment: Can you please explain more on the second solution. are you saying that a language server is capable of rendering html content upon receiving the text content of file (when file is opened and/or updated) and send it back to the text editor so it is able to set it as editor body?

Comment: Actually what I wanted to clarify is that one time rendering operation is not enough for my requirement. I need my custom js code to communicate with vscode and manipulate html/text content upon user interaction - after initial ui rendering is completed.